# Possible bug in using ClippingStyle inside of the GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: geographics

Using Mathematica 12.0 the following code:

```
 GeoRegionValuePlot[<|Entity["Country", "Italy"] -> 300, 
  Entity["Country", "France"] -> 100, 
  Entity["Country", "Spain"] -> 1 |>, ClippingStyle -> {Blue, Purple},
  PlotRange -> {10, 200}]
```

results in both Italy and Spain being coloured in blue. The example in the help about the population in the South America gives the same mistake.

Is it an issue for somebody else?

Comment: I can confirm that I also have this issue in 12.0. Evaluating the first example for ClippingStyle in the documentation displays this bug.